# In what cases doesn't a `div` take 100% of its container space?

Tags: html, css

I used to think that `<div>` elements always take 100% of their container space when no width is specified (since they're block elements). However in my latest webapp I'm running into a situation when a `<div>` will only take as much space as its content.

For example, I've a `#content-body` that is at least 800px wide, but a `<div>text</div>` in it only takes like 30px. In my all other apps I swear all my divs used to take 100% of the space.

I wonder why that happens. Have I set some properties wrong somewhere? I'd like to find out general cases when a `<div>` would be squeezed to take as little space as possible.

Comment: Is that div floated? Or set as `display: inline`?

Comment: There are several reasons why this could happen, for example if you float the div. Could you maybe provide a code example?

Comment: Generally, CSS does not speak of element types. It doesn't matter whether it is a div or a span - what matters are its CSS properties. A span with a specific set of display and box model properties will behave the same as a div with the same set of properties.

Comment: Can you provide some code that illustrates this behavior? Preferably in a codepen. You probably set something like `display: inline-block` on an element that relates to your div somehow.

Comment: take a look at div style using developer tools, especially at `display` value, check if the previous floating is cleared

Comment: Also check the margins. Or maybe you misspelled its tag name. Unrecognised elements are mostly treated as inline ones.

Comment: Thanks all. I will look into all these suggestions and report back once I have more clues about what is happening.